# Android Wear runnable for vibration works only in debug or with an active screen

Tags: java, android, android-handler, android-intentservice, android-vibration

i'm facing a big issue with android wearable development.
I've got a Runnable task that runs with an Handler every 100mS (it's purpose is to behave just like a chronograph) on my phisical wearable device (that's a Motorola 360).
When the Runnable task is alive for 20 seconds, i call a custom IntentService called VibratorService that makes the device vibrate with a defined pattern for an undefined amount of time.
When the Runnable task reaches 30 seconds alive, i dismiss the VibratorService so that the device stops vibrating while Runnable goes on and on.

For make device vibrating i decided to use an IntentService because calling directly Vibrator.vibrate() from the running task wasn't enough: Vibration stops when wearable goes in sleep mode. I should have implemented a wake lock to make it work continuously but i don't want to do it because it keeps the screen active.

During my debug sessions i've noticed that my app works good in every condition. Unfortunately doesn't works well in sleep mode when wearable is not connected in debug mode to the handheld device (that's an OnePlus) and this makes it very difficult to debug and understand where the problem is. The only way i found to make it work in this scenario is to continue moving phisically the wearable in order to keep it awake.

I can't understand if the Runnable task/Handler works properly or if there are some problem in VibratorService start or if there's an issue in Vibrator class usage when wearable is sleeping and debug is turned off. In my opinion i think is something related to the Runnable or to the Handler, but i'm not sure.

Someone of you is aware about a different behavior in debug/non debug  sleep mode for Runnable/Handler/IntentService/Vibrator?
How can i make it work?

Here you are the Runnable task code:

```
private class TimerRunnable implements Runnable {

            private boolean _isRunning;
            private boolean _isPaused;
            private long startTime;
            private long elapsedTime;


            public long getElapsedTime(){
                return elapsedTime;
            }

            public boolean isRunning(){
                return _isRunning;
            }

            public void resetRunnable(){
                _isRunning = false;
                _isPaused = false;
                startTime = 0;
                elapsedTime = 0;
            }

            public void pauseRunnable(){
                _isRunning = false;
                _isPaused = true;
            }

            public void startRunnable(){
                _isRunning = true;
                if(!_isPaused)
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                else
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {

                if(_isRunning) {
                    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    if(elapsedTime>=30000)
                        stopNotification();
                    else if(elapsedTime>=20000)
                        startNotification();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(this, REFRESH_RATE);
                }
            }
        }
```

The start/stop vibration service functions:

```
  @Override
    public void startNotification() {

        //Start vibration
        Log.i("VibrationNotification", "Start vibrate notification service");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VibratorService.class);
        intent.addCategory(VibratorService.TAG);
        intent.putExtra(VibratorService.PARAM_DELAY, delay);
        intent.putExtra(VibratorService.PARAM_SLEEPDURATION, sleepDuration);
        intent.putExtra(VibratorService.PARAM_VIBRATIONDURATION, vibrationDuration);
        context.startService(intent);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stopNotification() {

        //Stop vibration
        Log.i("VibrationNotification", "Stop vibrate notification service");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VibratorService.class);
        intent.addCategory(VibratorService.TAG);
        context.stopService(intent);
        isRunning = false;
    }
```

The vibrator service:

```
public class VibratorService  extends IntentService{
    public static final String TAG = "VibratorService";

    public static final String PARAM_DELAY = "Delay";
    public static final String PARAM_VIBRATIONDURATION = "VibrationDuration";
    public static final String PARAM_SLEEPDURATION = "SleepDuration";

    private boolean stopServiceRequest;

    public VibratorService(){
        super("VibratorService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.i("VibrationService", "OnHandleIntent");

        //Set pattern
        long[] pattern = new long[]{intent.getLongExtra(PARAM_DELAY, 0),
                intent.getLongExtra(PARAM_VIBRATIONDURATION, 0),
                intent.getLongExtra(PARAM_SLEEPDURATION, 0)};

        //Set vibrator
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        //Continue vibrating
        stopServiceRequest = false;
        while(true){
            Log.i("VibrationService", "Vibration is up and running");
            v.vibrate(pattern, 1);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(pattern[0] + pattern[1] + pattern[2]);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(stopServiceRequest){
                v.cancel();
                Log.i("VibrationService", "Stop service request. End service.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("VibrationService", "OnDestroy");
        stopServiceRequest = true;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checking, are you running 6.0 on the watch and therefore subject to Doze mode?

Comment: I'm running android 6.0.1, android wear version is 1.4.0.2580363. I think that could be the Doze mode, but i can't tell you for sure because i've got problems only in non-debug context. I should try with AlarmManager instead of handler/Runnable, but i don't know if it is suitable for creating a precise chrongraph. Suggestions?